# Showing type of newline character in Emacs

Tags: emacs

How can I have Emacs display the type of new character?

I am looking for something similar to what Notepadd does (see below). I read that Emacs comes with `M-x whitespace-mode` but this doesn't seem to show the type of ASCII control character the file uses to represent linebreaks. Am I missing anything?

[image]

Note: I asked this question in [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/580515/showing-type-of-newline-character-in-emacs) but did not get an answer in 3+ months so I am hoping to try here now.

Comment: You did get an answer, and it's basically the same answer.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to this answer, and I think whitespace mode could be it... or at least it's mechanism to rewrite a character via a display_mapping.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the bottom left of your window, you have a cryptic string like `1:@**-`. Hover over the colon, it'll tell you something like "line endings: unix, mouse-1 to toggle". (Incidentally, the 1 left to it is the coding system, iso-8859-1 in my case)

Comment: And if you set the buffer to Unix line endings when the file contains DOS line endings, it will show the CRs as `\M`s at the end of each line

Comment: Thanks Urich and @MichaelMrozek. I was hoping that Emacs had a mode or package that would show all the special character types on the buffer (basically an enhanced whitespace mode), but I guess this is as close as I can get to it. Thanks again.